# Node.js - Socket.IO 1.0 - Timeout event

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, timeout

I'm using Socket.IO (the latest version 1.1.0) to exchange messages with an Android app (the client). 
I would like to set a timeout (5s for example) to check if my client is still connected or not (I would like to handle the case when the Android app crashes). Moreover, I would like to generate an event when a this timeout occurs. 
What I want to do looks like this:

1/ Set the timeout

```
var socket = require('socket.io')({
   //options go here
  'timeout': 5000 //set the timeout to 5s
});
```

2/ Handle timeout event:

```
socket.on('timeout', function(){
   //my treatment
});
```

But I don't find any implementation to handle the timeout.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what the timeout setting handles.  The timeout is how long the server will wait for a re-connect before it tears down that connection.  You probably don't want to set it that short; possibly even leave it at the default.

Socketio automatically sends heartbeats by default.  You really should just need to assign a function to run when the 'disconnect' message is received on the server side.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
       console.log('a user connected');
       socket.on('disconnect', function(){
           console.log('user disconnected');
       });
});
```

Check out this post for more information about the heartbeat:
[Advantage/disadvantage of using socketio heartbeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061362/advantage-disadvantage-of-using-socketio-heartbeats)