# (MEAN) Socket.io - Transport Polling Overload - Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm running on a MEAN stack, and upon connected to `socket.io` my server console goes wild with GET requests that go like this while grunt is serving:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438905856120-1645 200 49ms
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438905856204-3489 200 41ms
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438905856408-1648 200 16ms
```

etc.

What is transport polling? I'll I'm trying to do is follow Socket.io's instructions to emit a chat message to the server console. Below I'll include the relevant snippets of code:

**app.js (server-side)**

```
socketio.sockets.on('connection', require('./config/socketio'));
```

**Socket.io configuration (client-side)**

```
socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("hello");
    // socket.address = socket.handshake.address !== null ?
    //         socket.handshake.address.address + ':' + socket.handshake.address.port :
    //         process.env.DOMAIN;

    socket.connectedAt = new Date();

    // Call onDisconnect.
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log("goodbye");
      onDisconnect(socket);
      console.info('[%s] DISCONNECTED', socket.address);
    });

    // Call onConnect.
    onConnect(socket);
    console.info('[%s] CONNECTED', socket.address);
});
```

**Controller.js**

```
var socket = io();

$scope.sendMessage = function(){
  socket.emit('chat message', $('.new-message').val());
  $('.new-message').val('');
  return false;
};
```

**html**

```
 <form class="message-form" ng-submit="sendMessage()">
    <input style="width:100%" class="new-message" placeholder="Type your message here..." ng-model="newMessage" ng-trim="false">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
```

*EDIT*

**app.js**(server side)

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
  serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1577
@Maxwell2022 commented on Jun 4, 2014

"It's due to the version of socket.io. I had to downgrade to v0.9.x because I could not find any documentation about the way to perform handshake with version v1.0.x"

Comment: Don't know if that's part of the issue, but I don't really know how to change the version of Socket.io. I just installed it with NPM

Comment: These are heartbeat packets. Read more about them here before you try to get rid of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061362/advantage-disadvantage-of-using-socketio-heartbeats

Comment: I'll give it a look. It's definitely emitting those "packets" at a much faster rate than every 15 seconds. . . more like every 15ms. Kinda overheating my computer. The rapid pace makes it difficult to debug. 

Still trying to figure out why the `$scope.sendMessage()` function doesn't work...I'll keep you updated.

Comment: there's missing initialization code for sockets in OP

Comment: How do you mean? I'll update how I setup my server...

Comment: what's `io()` on client?

Comment: Remark about installing required version via npm. You can use `@` symbol to specify version of the package you need. [Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: `"socket.io": "^1.0.6",`
`"socket.io-client": "^1.0.6",`
`"socketio-jwt": "^2.0.2"`

Comment: Where is `io()` defined for controller?

Comment: hmm. I'm not really sure what i() does? Is that a method from the Socket.io libarary? According to the Socket.io docs, I define `socket = io()` and use this to emit the actual message. Doesn't work though. See OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85367/discussion-between-kirill-slatin-and-peter-ward).