# Socket.IO: Detect disconnected sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a `socket.io` server/client. When a `client` safely disconnects, on the server side, the line

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {

});
```

is called.

However, if the client server crashes, then `socket.on('disconnect')` is never called; I know this because I recursively print out `wss.sockets.connected.length` and the number does not decrease.

How can I check that such a crash has happened on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should eventually receive the disconnect event, because socket.io has a heartbeat mechanism. I don't think there is any other way to detect a client crash. It does take some time though.

Heartbeat has been explained well here:

[Advantage/disadvantage of using socketio heartbeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061362/advantage-disadvantage-of-using-socketio-heartbeats)

Answer (score 0):

When server calls disconnect(), the reason given to disconnect handler is: io server disconnect. And when server stops, the reason is: transport close.
So you can check this by adding a condition:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
  if (reason === 'transport close'){
    console.log('Server Crashed');
  } 
});
```