# Tell server that user is no more on internet

Tags: node.js, cordova, socket.io, phonegap-plugins

I am new to node.js and trying to develop group chat using node.js and socket.io. I am able to do group chat also able to manage data in the system.

Now, the problem with me is with offline users i.e not connected to internet.
I am having connection stream of this user and as if I do receiverUserSocket.emit("sendMsg",data) there is no way to verify if this user received message or not.
Yes, there is an event .on("disconnect") but I am getting delay of approx 30 - 40 seconds.

Is there any way we can identify that the user to whom we want to send message is online or offline.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use socket.io heartbeats - assuming you're using socket.io.

Heartbeats and the problem with detecting a terminated connection are well explained here:

[Advantage/disadvantage of using socketio heartbeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061362/advantage-disadvantage-of-using-socketio-heartbeats)

Keep in mind that you can control heartbeat timeout values (thus forcing the disconnect event to appear much faster), as explained here:

[Controlling the heartbeat timeout from the client in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815231/controlling-the-heartbeat-timeout-from-the-client-in-socket-io)

But that might put much more strain on your server.

Comment: Thanks! for your prompt reply to my question.
yes, we can do that in a way you suggested but at the same time I don't want to have server load or continuous ping to client from server. What I am looking for is some method which could return me the validity of socket .emit, like if it actually worked and receiver received what was expected or not.

Comment: Thing is, as explained in my first link, there really is no other way. You basically have a choice - either send heartbeats more frequently, or send more messages to disconnected clients. Perhaps strike some kind of balance between both.

Comment: How about keeping timestamp at client side when it just got disconnected and request server against this time frame for all pending or missed messages when connected back.

Comment: That is a completely different problem though. If you want to have the client receive missed messages then yes, you can do something like that. But your server will still be sending messages that no one will receive.

Comment: well actually in node.js we are having an event .on("disconnect") on this event I may remove this diconnected user from group of people to send it and keeping log of that in database. Now the only concern was to handle those 30 - 40 seconds of delay to this event which I am trying to handle.

Comment: Yes, so the only thing you can do is increase heartbeat frequency. Any other solution will basically have to do the same thing.