# Detect user switch page using socket node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis

I'm trying unsubscribe from a Redis channel when the user go to other page inside the website. I have tried detect a disconnect socket event when the user clicks a link but the event is never triggered.

```
// Do things

req.socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("Disconnected");
    conexion.punsubscribe();
});
```

Do you know what socket event could I use to catch this action ?

Thanks.

Comment: disconnect event only triggered when the page is closed.

Answer (score 2):

User disconnection isn't so simple in socket.io, as explained here:

[Tell server that user is no more on internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009129/tell-server-that-user-is-no-more-on-internet/32009603#32009603)

Though in your case, you could perhaps have links that don't immediately redirect the user. Instead, they could run some JS onClick that disconnects the socket manually, and then redirects the user to the requested address. But that would require changing every single link on your page to run JavaScript instead, so it could potentially require a lot of work.